# Have bootstrap dropdown select option inline with text field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a horiztonal form, but I have one bit that is using "form-inline". I have it almost working, but
I am trying to get an inline form to behave the way I want, but I seem to be stuck.

This is what I have at the moment ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Fgj9/)):

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email address</label>
     <div class="col-lg-10">
         <div class="form-inline">
             <select class="form-control">
                 <option selected="selected">http://</option>
                 <option>https://</option>
             </select>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="website" placeholder="Enter website"/>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have two problems:

**1. When the screen is full size, I want the text input to take up the remaining room:**

[image]

**2. I always want to keep the "select" box to the left of the input field, I dont want them to jump to two lines**

[image]

I have tried using  with various column lengths, but that doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Set width for the drop down to 15% and width for the field for 75%. Then place them in a responsive container and as the site resizes they should stay the correct relative size. The only issue with this is once it gets to mobile sizes 15% of the container width will be very small, cutting off the text in the drop down. You can adjust the responsive.css so that at that size the width is something like 30% and 60% instead.

Comment: Wow - so obvious now. Thanks, works perfectly. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Please add solution to jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set width for the drop down to 15% and width for the field for 75%. Then place them in a responsive container and as the site resizes they should stay the correct relative size. The only issue with this is once it gets to mobile sizes 15% of the container width will be very small, cutting off the text in the drop down. You can adjust the responsive.css so that at that size the width is something like 30% and 60% instead.

Glad it worked!